# How do I send a gmail email in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, gmail

I want to send an email, but it gives me an error.

I have this code:

```
Sub sendMail(ByVal title As String, ByVal content As String)
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25)
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("name@gmail.com", "password")
    Dim mail As New MailMessage("name@gmail.com", "name@gmail.com", title, content)
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
End Sub
```

I have a try catch which tries to call this method, it doesnt work so the catch runs and i get thes exception: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b6sm3176487lae.0 - gsmtp` Why do I get this error? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gmail uses SMTP over SSL on port 465.

Try doing:

```
  Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
  ...
  SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
  ...
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought was the problem with the port, thanks

Comment: Ok the port I used was the right one but it was the EnableSsl I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this - I know it works.

```
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")

    Mail.Subject = "Security Update"
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("name@gmail.com")
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("name@gmail.com", "password") '<-- Password Here

    Mail.To.Add(address & "@gmail.com") 'I used ByVal here for address

    Mail.Body = "" 'Message Here

    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
```

Comment: The thing to note was the SMTP port. I thought it was 587, not 465 or 25.

Comment: So is it supposed to be 587 or 465?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with google account, you need to switch off some security settings. After sending email over and over, I received email on one of my support account (for google), the email were:

```
You recently changed your security settings so that your Google Account [trdjoko@gmail.com] is no longer protected by modern security standards. 

If you did not make this change 
Please review your Account Activity page at https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity to see if anything looks suspicious. Whoever made the change knows your password; we recommend that you change it right away. 

If you made this change 
Please be aware that it is now easier for an attacker to break into your account. You can make your account safer again by undoing this change at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps then switching to apps made by Google such as Gmail to access your account.   
Sincerely,
The Google Accounts team
```

So I switched of additional security and i worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port to 587. Port 25 does not support SSL.

Answer (score 0):

A super easy way of doing this(without changing any security settings) is by using [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) and my [IFTTT Maker.net libary](http://www.mediafire.com/download/39vn1rx0e5tix2y/ifttt.vb)

First, in IFTTT create a new recipe that's triggered by the Maker channel and name the event "send_gmail".

Then, select the Gmail engine and click "Send an email", and replace To with {{value1}}, subject with {{value2}} and message/body with {{value3}}

After that, in Visual studio, add ifttt.vb to your project. Now for the code:

```
      Try
    makechannel.scode = "your account ID"
    makechannel.fireevent("send_gmail", "TO", "SUBJECT", "MESSAGE")
   'code goes here if done
    Catch ex As Exception
        'code goes here if it fails
    End Try
```

Then fill in your account ID. You can find it at ifttt.com/maker

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I Have written the class which can perform this task easyly.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class GGSMTP_GMAIL
    Dim Temp_GmailAccount As String
    Dim Temp_GmailPassword As String
    Dim Temp_SMTPSERVER As String
    Dim Temp_ServerPort As Int32
    Dim Temp_ErrorText As String = ""
    Dim Temp_EnableSSl As Boolean = True
    Public ReadOnly Property ErrorText() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_ErrorText
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property EnableSSL() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Temp_EnableSSl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Temp_EnableSSl = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property GmailAccount() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_GmailAccount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Temp_GmailAccount = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property GmailPassword() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_GmailPassword
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Temp_GmailPassword = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property SMTPSERVER() As String
        Get
            Return Temp_SMTPSERVER
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Temp_SMTPSERVER = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ServerPort() As Int32
        Get
            Return Temp_ServerPort
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int32)
            Temp_ServerPort = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal GmailAccount As String, ByVal GmailPassword As String, Optional ByVal SMTPSERVER As String = "smtp.gmail.com", Optional ByVal ServerPort As Int32 = 587, Optional ByVal EnableSSl As Boolean = True)
        Temp_GmailAccount = GmailAccount
        Temp_GmailPassword = GmailPassword
        Temp_SMTPSERVER = SMTPSERVER
        Temp_ServerPort = ServerPort
        Temp_EnableSSl = EnableSSl
    End Sub
    Public Function SendMail(ByVal ToAddressies As String(), ByVal Subject As String, ByVal BodyText As String, Optional ByVal AttachedFiles As String() = Nothing) As Boolean
        Temp_ErrorText = ""
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage
        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(Temp_SMTPSERVER)
        Mail.Subject = Subject
        Mail.From = New MailAddress(Temp_GmailAccount)
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Temp_GmailAccount, Temp_GmailPassword) '<-- Password Here
        Mail.To.Clear()
        For i As Int16 = 0 To ToAddressies.Length - 1
            Mail.To.Add(ToAddressies(i))
        Next i
        Mail.Body = BodyText
        Mail.Attachments.Clear()

        If AttachedFiles IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Int16 = 0 To AttachedFiles.Length - 1
                Mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachedFiles(i)))
            Next
        End If

        SMTP.EnableSsl = Temp_EnableSSl
        SMTP.Port = Temp_ServerPort

        Try
            SMTP.Send(Mail)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Temp_ErrorText = ex.Message.ToString
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```

Its the way, how to use class:

```
 Dim GGmail As New GGSMTP_GMAIL("MyFromAddress1@gmail.com", "AccPassword", )

        Dim ToAddressies As String() = {"ToAddress1@gmail.com", "ToAddress2@gmail.com"}
        Dim attachs() As String = {"d:\temp_Excell226.xlsx", "d:\temp_Excell224.xlsx", "d:\temp_Excell225.xlsx"}
        Dim subject As String = "My TestSubject"
        Dim body As String = "My text goes here ...."
        Dim result As Boolean = GGmail.SendMail(ToAddressies, subject, body, attachs)
        If result Then
            MsgBox("mails sended successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox(GGmail.ErrorText, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
```

Hope this helps. Good coding