# What is wrong with this code that should send some email with google?

Tags: vb.net, email

```
Shared Sub sendMail(ByVal title As String, ByVal content As String)
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
    Dim mail As New MailMessage(username, username, title, content)
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
End Sub
```

I got the result of

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail.'
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

What did I do wrong? Should I enable IMAP first at google?

My code is based on [How do I send a gmail email in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153542/how-do-i-send-a-gmail-email-in-vb-net)

If I use port 587 instead of 465 I got

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at'
```

Using port 25 yield

```
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.200.109:25
```

Using 465 yield the original error

Comment: See this it can be helpful [How do I send a gmail email in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153542/how-do-i-send-a-gmail-email-in-vb-net)

Comment: Ah I found it again. I forget to mention, my code is based on that code. As you see I already add smtpserver.enablessl= true. Still doesn't work

Comment: Did you try different ports? I think Google uses either 25, 465 or 587.

Comment: The answer says I got to use 465. Let me try the others

Comment: That answer is dated four years back, things can change ;). -- However as none of them worked I did a little more digging... It seems you might have to [**turn on a setting called "Allow less secure apps"**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465275) on your Google account for it to work sending emails with. The problem could be that your application doesn't support the required security protocols by default, in which case you might want to try [**fiddling with them first**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29221917).